# How do you allow plugins to be updated using the GUI without breaking your subversion repository?

Tags: plugins, svn

Development on a WordPress installation is under Subversion version control. We're not using externals to link in the plugins - the plugins are getting installed / updated by non-developers in charge of content.

This causes issues within the repository, especially for plugins that are already under version control and are just being updated to the latest version, since updating a plugin deletes the directory (including all the .svn folders) and then re-creates it.

Here's a typical scenario, that's causing me no end of grief:

1. Put an existing WordPress site under version control in a fresh repo. This existing site ALREADY has some plugins. Some of those plugins are out of date
2. Now, go into the admin and update those plugins
3. run `svn st` and you see the following:

   ~  addthis

   ~  google-analytics-for-wordpress

   etc...

The tilde ~ is especially nasty because it means "duh, I dunno wha happuh", and SVN just cacks. Even copying, deleting, removing, restoring, moving back, attempting to commit - nope.

Many people recommend using svn:externals or manually FTPing the updates, which is all fine and dandy, but I'd just like to be able to use the UI as God intended. From what I can see in core, there's no hook that can be used to convince WP not to delete the folder, or the .svn folder. Is there something that can be done?

Comment: Tried the following: copied each of the plugins to pluginname_BAK, then ran `rm -r pluginname` and then `svn rm pluginname`. To my utter surprise, when I tried to commit I then got `svn:/trunk/wp-content/plugins/pluginname is out of date`. SVN hell.

Comment: Have you considered switching to Git and using a `.gitignore`?

Comment: I agree with @toscho, this is a great reason to switch to Git. Although, I don't ignore the plugins, I update them using the GUI in a development environment, and then push the changes to my production environment. It's a great workflow and it allows one to easily identify changes, review plugin changes for potential vulnerabilities or incompatibilities, and it allows for an easy "undo" if something breaks.

Comment: I should probably check out Git eventually, but it's avoiding the question regarding SVN, which is what this project is on and I can't change that right now. Now how is .gitignore different from svn:ignore? Are you suggesting I put an ignore on my plugins dir? That would be fine, but then I have to upgrade the plugins again on the PROD environment, which could lead to more outage time than I'd like, since if there are any dependencies on the plugins, those would potentially be broken until the update were finished.

Comment: git's ignore is no different than svn's ignore, so if one isn't a solution for you, then switching to git isn't going to help either. Bottom line is that either you version-control the plugins, or you don't. If you version control them, then you have to disable the built-in-upgrade methods. If you don't version-control them, then you can use the built-in upgrader, but you may have to do it on multiple hosts if you have your repo exported to more than one of them.

Comment: @Otto: "Bottom line is that either you version-control the plugins, or you don't" is not accurate. With git, the .git directory is only in the root of the repository, not in every sub-directory as is the case with svn. Therefore, with Git, this wouldn't be an issue. It's moot because TomAuger says he can't use Git here, but I wanted to clarify that for other visitors.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes I'm afraid that you're out of date, svn no longer puts .svn folders into every subdirectory, as of Subversion client 1.7. See http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng

Comment: @Otto I guess I am out of date! I see that you since offered that as an answer to the question, thanks. [High five]

Comment: Subversion creates a .svn  in **every** directory of your repo; Git only creates one .git directory (in the root of your repo). Therefore, Git may be the better choice here.

Comment: @bungeshea Take a look at Otto's answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74122/3687. Since 1.7 Subversion DOES NOT put a .svn in every directory of your working copy.

Comment: Move to git or mercurial. You could use bitbucket for private code hostings. Very nice and reliable, as many private repos as you want with at most 5 Developers. HTTPS pushing pulling or ssh pushing and pulling! Awsome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Real answer, taking all the above into account:

Regarding `.svn` directories: Subversion 1.7 was released a little over a year ago ( http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2011-10/0152.shtml ) and the working copies no longer contain .svn directories in every folder. They contain a single .svn directory in the root, along with fairly substantial performance improvements. Today, SVN is up to version 1.7.7. You should upgrade your svn client to eliminate this as any sort of problem.

That answers the Original Question, because WP deleting the directories and re-creating them is no longer really an issue. It won't mess up a Working Copy made by Subversion 1.7 or above. However, it doesn't answer the larger question of repository management with regards to production deployment and dev/testing environments.

Basically, how you manage your production machines is up to you. If you actually have a real "production" environment, then you should use a permissions scheme and/or plugins to disable the ability of users to upgrade the system directly. Users can't change production. That's sort of the point of calling it "production". Changes in such a case would be made by devs and rolled through testing and/or QA systems first. If you have such an environment and really need that sort of level of control, then disabling the upgrader entirely would be the preferred way to go.

Heck, I use just that sort of environment myself, although I control dev, testing, and production all the way through. The whole site is in an SVN repo. Some of it indeed uses externals (I use WP trunk, a few plugins I use as trunk versions), some of it doesn't and is local to the repo. For me, deploying changes to production means doing an `svn up` on those boxes, basically. Changes can't be made directly on those boxes filesystems.

On the other hand, some sites I run just straight up live, with regular backups. If my personal site is wonky for a bit, then it doesn't really affect me any. I use the WP updater on those just fine. Now, I don't run those sites in a repo, I just have regular backups of the whole thing. In point of fact, I use VaultPress on my personal sites, but any method of backup is a good idea. This is a different type of management, one where I don't need a dev/testing environment.

WordPress works fine with any sort of system you wish to create around it, but that system is external to WordPress, and how you manage it is a question of not of WP but of how you want to manage it, really.

Comment: Hey @Otto, thanks for the detailed writeup. I'm in the unfortunate situation of having inherited a Linux server without a lot of knowledge about server administration - this explains my out of date Subversion (and probably a host of other things). I'll read the literature and figure out how to upgrade it, right soon! I think it might be interesting to look into writing a plugin that allows tighter integration of the WP auto-updater and various version control systems, such that the updater was a notifier, and the actual update happens through the VC system. Maybe someday I'll have the time!

Comment: Thanks Otto! I've accepted this answer as the most complete. The bounty got mistakenly awarded to the wrong answer (and an incomplete one at that), and there's no way to undo it. Should make that other user happy though - I daresay you hardly need the additional rep.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested yet, but `add_filter('upgrader_clear_destination', array(&$this, 'delete_old_plugin'), 10, 4);` looks good. You will find it in `wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php`
Remove the filter before updating your plugins. This could be a bit tricky because you have to search for the correct function name to be remove. [Toscho wrote a post about removing anonymous hooks (german)](http://toscho.de/2012/wordpress-anonyme-hooks-deaktivieren/).

But `apply_filters('upgrader_pre_install', true, $hook_extra);` (same file as above) seems to be the better solution. Hook into 'upgrader_pre_install' and save your .svn directory. Also hook into 'upgrader_post_install', this hook will be done after the update. After updating the plugin, simply copy back your .svn directory.

Comment: that's an interesting approach. sounds like a heck of a lot of custom work - basically writing a plugin to allow you to update other plugins. I wonder whether this is the basic premise behind how svn-auto-upgrade plugin is supposed to work. Sad thing is, I had that plugin installed and it still didn't do the trick...

Comment: @TomAuger I have now downloaded and inspect the plugin code. And it does exactly what I wrote in my answer. But it need the ability to execute `shell_exec()`. I think `shell_exec()` is deactivated on your server (security) and this is the reason why the plugin does not work properly. You can try to comment out the parts with `shell_exec()` and the svn-commands and do the svn-commands by hand.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, Ralf! I wonder whether the filesystem API couldn't handle some of the things shell_exec() was attempting to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manage your WordPress install through version control, then I don't see a way how can you do so along with updating the plugins from WordPress admin panel only.

Ideally it should be like this:

- Checkout a copy of your repo on local.
- Update the plugin from WP admin.
- Test
- Commit
- Checkout the latest version on production (checkout meaning deployment of those commits)

And this works flawlessly with GIT. With SVN, it can be an issue since it has a `.svn` directory in each directory, but like Otto suggested SVN 1.7 can help you here as there will only be a single `.svn` directory in the root.

Comment: Yeah, that totally doesn't work. It would be nice. But it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @TomAuger I work with the above mentioned process all the time and it WORKS!

Comment: I guess it works for you, but anyway.

Comment: @TomAuger So much for being a developer & just saying "doesn't work" instead of actually stating the issue.

Comment: The issue is that your "process" is so vague and generic that it's not a solution. Look at your steps: checkout on local, do update, test, commit, checkout on production. That's a basic workflow for any situation. Furthermore, it's weird. Are you really going to "checkout" the repository on your production? What if your production is already under version control - you don't want to check it out, you want to do `svn update`. Are you sure you meant "checkout"? At any rate, what breaks is your step #2. As soon as you update the plugin, WP deletes the .svn folder. So now you cannot commit.

Comment: Gotcha! It works well with GIT since there is only a single `.git` folder in repo root. And yes "Production" in meant to be run by a repo checkout for ease.

Comment: Tom: If you're using SVN 1.7 and up, there is no .svn directory in each folder anymore, just one in the root of the working copy. His process works fine for that case, because there is no .svn directory to be deleted by WP and to hork up the working copy. Try upgrading your SVN client. The 1.7 client works fine with older 1.6 servers too, so no worries there.

Comment: Thanks Otto for the clarification. I should apologize @Ashfame for my snarky tone.

Comment: I still don't think @Ashfame's solution is universal. Some plugins delete files, others add files. In those circumstances, more work is to be done. In between his steps, there should be at least an `svn st` and `svn add` and possibly `svn rm` to handle those circumstances. Probably an `svn st | grep '^\?' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add` etc...

Comment: @TomAuger: Yes, but that would be the case whether you upgraded manually or via the built-in process. If you want the plugins to be in your repo, then you have to manage them, and how you manage them is really up to you. One method is using externals and disabling the built-in updater. Another method is to use the built-in updater and then do the proper repo management yourself. Another is to use svn:ignore to ignore those directories. This isn't an svn specific problem, it's a problem of production vs. dev/testing management.

Comment: Like Otto says production vs. dev/testing management, I handle everything via repo. I walk along the line of having the whole app in repo, so that repo's checkout is actually capable of running off the install. I don't upgrade things from WP admin side (I disable the power if needed), and things work just perfect with GIT. Never ran into an issue with this, cuz it becomes equivalent of uploading files manually, and everything fires correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a plugin was created to help with just this.

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/svn-auto-upgrade/trunk/

Or, just type "SVN Auto Upgrade" into the Plugin browser in your WP back-end.

Comment: Nope, maybe that worked before, but it ain't working now. I'll update my question, hopefully get some eyes on it.